# Send mail from Exchange Server

Tags: c#, .net, smtp, exchange-server

I want to send mail from exchange server without password. I use the following code snippet :

```
MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
msg.From = new MailAddress("kavitham@test.com");
msg.To.Add(new MailAddress("kavitham@sample.com"));
msg.Subject = "Reg : Mail test";
msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
msg.Body = "<html><body>" + strMsg +  "</body></html>";
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("IP of Server", 25);
client.Host = "IP of Server";
client.Send(msg);
```

But the mail is not sent. Is there any other settings for Exchange server need to be done ?

Comment: What is the error message you get back?

Comment: I didn't get any error message.

Comment: So it sends ok? So what makes you think it isn't working? If you don't receive it could be a spam filter blocking it somewhere along the way, or your exchange server not releasing it for whatever reason. If you don't get error then .Net part is likely fine

Comment: put a try catch in there for debugging

Comment: I check with spam filter and also try with different mail accounts.. But non e of mails got

Comment: what are you trying it from? hotmail.. gmail?

Comment: sorry as i only deploy code in server.. i am unable to debug from server..

Comment: if the smtp refused to send an email, your application would generate an exception saying why it failed. What logging are you using? are you catching and handling the exception?

Comment: @KaviSuja: So if you can't debug it, how do you know there is no error? You need to handle the error and write it to a file. Then test it and look at the log file for the error. It will tell you what is wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 MailMessage msg = new MailMessage("noreply@test.com", "manager@test.com", "Notification For Lead / Admin ",
             "Emp Name :" + EmpName);
            msg.Body = "Emp Name : " + EmpName + "<br /><br >" + Environment.NewLine + timsheetMail;             

            msg.IsBodyHtml = true;

        msg.CC.Add(toMail); msg.CC.Add(admin);
            SmtpClient SMTPServer = new SmtpClient("mail.myserver.com", 25);
            SMTPServer.Timeout = 300000;
            SMTPServer.EnableSsl = false;
            SMTPServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("noreply@test.com", "passw0rd");
            SMTPServer.Send(mailObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

add this

```
smtpClient.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
```